# Generate Buckets for a range of floats

Tags: java

I have a range of weights (represented as floats).

For example

```
2.0197875
2.0197875
2.0197875
2.0197875
2.031247
2.0448067
2.0473573
2.0520945
2.0520945
2.0595925
2.0595925
2.076654
3.0265803
3.035842
3.0536165
3.1563497
3.1563497
3.1563497
3.433653
4.0345426
4.0947146
4.977886
4.9907994
5.0965066
8.852995
12.324477
```

Each float has a term associated with it.

I need an algorithm to distribute the term (according to it's weight) as evenly as possible into N buckets (configurable). If there are 10 terms and 5 buckets then ideally there would be 2 terms in each bucket. If there are terms with identical weights then they should be put in the same bucket.

I'm struggling to work out an algorithm to do this. I've done some research to try and find algorithms which would work but I don't know the math terminology used to describe this.

Can anybody assist?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share an example ? with inputs and expected outputs to clarify ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Do you mean even distribution of weights, i.e. total weights should be approximately equal, or even distribution of terms, i.e. total number of terms should be approximately equal for each bucket?

Comment: Apologies. I am after an evenly distributed number of terms , terms with the same weight should ideally live in the same bucket. I have done some basic research but didn't know how to explain what I wanted with the correct language.

Answer (score 2):

You have `n` items that you want to distribute "evenly" into `k` buckets.

There are two very simple ways that might work, depending on your need.

The easiest way is to take the range, divide it by `k`, and have a bucket for every `n/k` value. In your example, your range is `(12.324477 - 2.0197875) = 10.3046895`. Let's say you have 5 buckets. The size of each bucket, then is `2.0609379`. So your first bucket contains items in the range `2.0197875 >= x < 4.0807254`. Next bucket is `4.0807254 >= x < 6.1416633`, etc.

The disadvantage of that approach is that some of your buckets will have a lot of items, and some will have none. But the *buckets* are evenly spaced. It's very easy to determine which bucket an item goes into, and it's easy to determine if a given value exists in any of your buckets.

Another way to do it is to take your items and place the first `n/k` in the first bucket, the next `n/k` in the second bucket, etc. You have 26 items in your example list. With 5 buckets, you end up with 4 buckets that have 5 items each, and one bucket with 6 items.

That puts approximately the same number of items into each bucket, but you could end up putting identical items into two different buckets. Given your sample data, the value `2.0595925` would end up in two different buckets. You can get around this by making sure that duplicate items always go into the same bucket, and adjusting the contents of later (or perhaps earlier) buckets accordingly. The biggest disadvantage of this approach is that it's more difficult to determine if an item exists in the list. You have to do a search to determine which bucket it might be in.

Which you pick is totally up to you. Do you want "evenly spaced" buckets, or do you want buckets that contain approximately the same number of items? Or do you want something else entirely? You have to define what "as evenly as possible" means.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Apologies, "Evenly spaced" wasn't well defined. Ideally I'd want buckets with roughly the same numbers of items.